# `assimilate_storage` not implemented for `ChainSpec`

Tags: chainspec

I have a slightly custom chain spec that makes regular chain spec serializable with serde to/from JSON.

In the impl of `sp_runtime::BuildStorage` I just forward `assimilate_storage` call to the underlying chain spec:

```rust
impl<GenesisConfig, Extensions> BuildStorage for SerializableChainSpec<GenesisConfig, Extensions>
where
    GenesisConfig: RuntimeGenesis,
{
    fn assimilate_storage(&self, storage: &mut Storage) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.chain_spec.assimilate_storage(storage)
    }
}
```

This worked great until I tried to run benchmarks, when it failed with:

```
Error: SubstrateCli(Input("`assimilate_storage` not implemented for `ChainSpec`."))
```

Not 100% sure what this means and what implementation should have looked like instead, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `BuildStorage` for `ChainSpec` was implementing `assimilate_storage` by returning the error you mentioned. It seems that back in the days I didn't implemented this function properly, but don't ask me why...

Nevertheless, after this [pr](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12720) it will be fixed.

Comment: Lovely, thanks!